# Ionic 3- How to view & download any file stored in firebase storage on a button click?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

I want to view or download files that are stored in firebase storage and the link/URL of that file is stored in a firebase table. I tried some code but it's not working. It's not even showing any error. also tell me how to view any file on button click depending on the file type.
[image: This my screen]

**Firebase table:**
[image]

**document.html code:**

```
<div>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let document of userDocuments">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>{{document.title}}</ion-card-title>
            <p>{{document.doc_name}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row wrap>
                <ion-col col-6>
                    <button
                    ion-button
                    color="button"
                    (click)="view(document)"><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>&nbsp;View</button>
               </ion-col>
               <ion-col col-6>
                   <button
                   ion-button
                   color="button"
                   (click)="download(document)"><ion-icon name="download"></ion-icon>&nbsp;Download</button>
               </ion-col>
           </ion-row>
       </ion-grid>
   </ion-card>
</div>
```

**document.ts code:**

```
view(Document)
{
    //View file code
}

download(Document)
{
    //alert(Document.path);
    console.log(Document.path);
    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    fileTransfer.download(Document.path, this.file.dataDirectory + Document.doc_name).then((entry) => {
        console.log('Download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        alert('Success');
        alert('Downloaded to : ' + entry.toURL());
    },(error) => {
        console.log('Download error: ' + error);
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    });
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me the result of "this.file.dataDirectory + Document.doc_name"?

Comment: Even I don't know this, I got this code from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/ , this.file.dataDirectory means "Persistent and private data storage within the application's sandbox using internal memory"

Comment: You can use console.log in your code and tell me what value you're getting.

Comment: But whenever I click download button it is showing "Native: tried accessing the FileTransfer plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator"

Comment: You will have to check on a device/simulator only. Ionic serve on browser will not help you here.

Comment: Yeah I did check but nothing happens on download button click and it is not even showing me an alert box alert('Error: ' + error); in case if there's any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165707/discussion-between-saksham-gupta-and-shreyas-pednekar).

Answer (score 0):

```
download(Document)
{
    //alert(Document.path);
    console.log(Document.path);
    const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    fileTransfer.download(Document.path, this.file.dataDirectory + Document.doc_name, true).then((entry) => {
        console.log('Download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        alert('Success');
        alert('Downloaded to : ' + entry.toURL());
    },(error) => {
        console.log('Download error: ' + error);
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    });
}
```

Just added one more parameter in download function *true* for *trustAllHosts*.

Give a try to this.